# How to handle java exception InputMismatchException along with custom exceptions?

Tags: java, exception

I'm making a simple program that is a guessing game all you need to do is guess the random number. As long as your not getting the correct answer it will keep asking for input.

I created two exceptions which is thrown if the input value is high or low which works.

I also needed to use another exception which is InputMismatchException but when its used its giving me an infinite loop. Instead of asking the user for input it just skips directly to the InputMismatchException. How do I get it to work with my custom exceptions?

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        final int min = 1, max = 50;
        final int random = (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);

        boolean status = false;
        int count = 0;

        while (status != true) {

            try {

                System.out.println("Guess a number from 1 to 50: ");
                int answer = scan.nextInt();

                if (answer < random) {

                    throw new InputTooLowException("");

                } else if (answer > random) {

                    throw new InputTooHighException("");

                } else if (answer == random) {

                    System.out.println("\n" + "Congratulations! You got it in " + count + " attempt/s");
                    status = true;
                }

            } catch (InputTooLowException e) {
                System.out.println("Too low. Try again.");
                status = false;
                count = count + 1;

            } catch (InputTooHighException e) {
                System.out.println("Too high. Try again.");
                status = false;
                count = count + 1;

            } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                System.out.println("Invalid Input");
                status = false;
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: This is **not** a good use of Exceptions. Like the name suggests, they are for _exceptional events_, e.g., errors that you can recover from. But this would be an expected outcome, no? A user won't guess right 100% of the time, right? Your could would be much more readable and simpler without exceptions (they also incur a performance penalty, btw).

Comment: I see, I think it can be done just by using the while loop and if else-if but this is a school activity and were told to implement exceptions.

Comment: Uff, I hate teachers like that. Just know that this is bad practice and that this kind of code wouldn't be accepted in any proper company. Send my regards to your teacher...
So, first off, why do you set `status` to false, even though it has to be false at that point anyway? Secondly, show us the definitions of those Exceptions. Are they subtypes of InputMismatchException? Why does the latter one even exists, if you never throw it?

Comment: About the status I was trying to find a way why it's looping so I was just trying out random stuff I'll edit it out since it doesn't make any sense. About the two other exception I just made them since it is required in the activity it just simply extends the Exception class then the constructor just contains super(message) both are the same. Then I'm trying to add the InputMismatchException in case the user inputs a string instead of int. I hope that answers your question.

Comment: How can the input be a string if you read into the `int answer`? It can't and you are not throwing that exception, so it can't be cought.
At least in the code you posted, which is why it won't even compile for me...

Comment: I don't know about my prof. but it is a feature of the program I guess so when a user inputs an invalid value it doesn't get counted as an attempt. Oh i see, now I added an else which throws the InputMismatchException it still loops infinitely though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This program works for me.
Again, I want to highlight that this is a bad/non-idiomatic use of Exceptions.

I highly recommend Joshua Blochs famous Book "Effective Java". Chapter 10, Item 69 is about this: "Use exceptions only for exceptional conditions".

The Carnegie Mellon University Software Engineering Institute also has this in their [coding guidelines](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/java/ERR50-J.+Use+exceptions+only+for+exceptional+conditions).

Now regarding the *infinite loop*: I didn't realize that `InvalidInputException` is not one of **your custom** Exceptions, but from java.util and thrown by `scan.nextInt`.

The [documentation of Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) says:

> When a scanner throws an InputMismatchException, the scanner will not pass the token that caused the exception, so that it may be retrieved or skipped via some other method.

That means, if you type in text, not a number, Scanner will let you know, but *not* simply throw away the input. You have to handle it yourself. E.g., by calling `next`. I have added a check `hasNext` here. A user could press Ctrl+d which means something like "End of File" (EOF). This closes the input stream. My check prevents an error here, but your call to `nextInt` may then throw a `NoSuchElementException`. This should be handled in real code, but I doubt your professor will notice.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        final int min = 1, max = 50;
        final int random = (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);

        boolean status = false;
        int count = 0;

        while (status != true) {

            try {

                System.out.println("Guess a number from 1 to 50: ");
                int answer = scan.nextInt();

                // Note that this is a _terrible_ use of Exceptions
                // and _bad practice_.
                if (answer < random) {

                    throw new InputTooLowException("");

                } else if (answer > random) {

                    throw new InputTooHighException("");

                } else if (answer == random) {

                    System.out.println("\n" + "Congratulations! You got it in " + count + " attempt/s");
                    status = true;
                }

            } catch (InputTooLowException e) {
                System.out.println("Too low. Try again.");
                count = count + 1;

            } catch (InputTooHighException e) {
                System.out.println("Too high. Try again.");
                count = count + 1;
            } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                System.out.println("Invalid Input");

                // Check if there actually is an invalid token
                if (scan.hasNext()) {
                    // Discard invalid token
                    scan.next();
                }
            }

        }

    }

    // Defining Exceptions here, but could do it in their own files.
    private static class InputTooHighException extends Exception {
                public InputTooHighException(String msg) { super(msg); }
    }

    private static class InputTooLowException extends Exception {
                public InputTooLowException(String msg) { super(msg); }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll keep it in mind thanks, but for now is there a way to handle the InputMismatchException? It is one of the features of the program that were told to recreate. So it doesn't stop working even if the user inputs a string. Edit: Yep the second block of code is what I had really in mind but you know school stuff we need to comply.

Comment: OK; I did not understand that you were talking about the case when the user enters invalid input and that the Exception was not **your custom Exception**.

Comment: Ok let me try to understand your explanation and why it was looping. So you said "Check if there actually is an invalid token" then if there is "Discard invalid token" so i guess toke means the input, then the reason why it was looping because before i did not discard the input so when it looped back the input was still invalid that's why it keeps on looping, so to fix it I needed to get rid of the invalid input. Edit: i tried it and it's working thanks a lot! this was really educational for me.